# Can I link multiple BOOST unit tests into a single test binary?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, boost, automated-tests

I've recently started trying to put a venerable and large (>1 million lines) program under test.  There are currently no unit tests.  Also, the program is linked as each individual file being linked together - there are no component libraries.  Furthermore, the objects are *highly* interdependent, and it is difficult (impossible?) to link to any object files without linking to at least half of them.

Yes, I know, my life sucks.

I'd like to do some refactoring (obviously), but I'd like to have some tests in place before I start moving things around.  My current idea is to compile a single "test program" which runs all of the tests I create. This would drastically simplify the linking issues that I have and let me focus on the real problems.  So I have two questions:

- **Is it possible to link multiple BOOST unit test files into one test executable?**
- **Is there a better solution?**

Comment: It look like there may be a way to do this.  Updates to follow.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I guess, this is precisely how to use boost test.
I would keep one short main.cpp file consisting of literally 2 lines:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "C++ Unit Tests for MyTangledLibrary"
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

And then I would keep adding test module *.cpp files compiled together into one executable

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
<< your include files >>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(FancyShmancyLogic)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestingIf2x3equals6)
{
  ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestingIf2x2equals4)
{
  ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Yes, you will be able to compile that main.cpp and all of your modules into one large executable.

Comment: When I try this, the test compiles and links, but upon execution I get:

    Test setup error: test tree is empty

Comment: You also need to include all your module *.cpp files into main.cpp. Otherwise the test runner does not know about your tests.

Comment: @Ace7k3, I thought it was bad practice to ever `#include` a `.cpp` file.  Is this an exception?

Comment: @Ace7k3: Compiling the .cpp files separately and linking them into a unit test executable works fine for me.

Comment: @tjwrona, include in the project not #include in the source.

Comment: @Ant I figured that out about a week later haha.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/single_header_customizations/multiple_translation_units.html

Comment: It would be nice if cmake can do this automatically